# use AdornedElementPlaceholder in normal ContentTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to implement a template for my TextBox which displays at the right of the TextBox a little Image like it can be achieved inside ValidationTemplates:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="TextBoxTemplate">
    <DockPanel>
        <Grid x:Name="image" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="3,0,0,0" Width="20" Height="20">
            <Ellipse Width="20" Height="20" Fill="Red" />
            <TextBlock Text="!" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" FontSize="16" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="7,-1" />
        </Grid>
        <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
    </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

But when I try to bind the TextBox.Template Property to this StaticResource:

```
<TextBox Template="{StaticResource TextBoxTemplate}" Text="Test">
```

it does not show the TextBox itself.

I found a workaround for this by placing another TextBox inside the ControlTemplate instead of the AdornedElementPlaceholder and Binding the different values (Text, Style etc.) to the TemplatedParent:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="TextBoxTemplate">
    <DockPanel DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
        <Grid x:Name="image" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="3,0,0,0" Width="20" Height="20">
            <Ellipse Width="20" Height="20" Fill="Red" />
            <TextBlock Text="!" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" FontSize="16" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="7,-1" />
        </Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}" Style="{Binding Style}" Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}" />
    </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

But this is a rather ugly approach because you have to bind each Property explicitly.

Is there another easier way?
How is the AdornedElementPlaceholder in ValidationTemplate done? Couldn't I use it for my ContentTemplate?

Cheers,
Ialokim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is what `AdornedElementPlaceholder` is used in conjunction with `Validation.ErrorTemplate`. In this case it will take original control and put it in a place of `AdornedElementPlaceholder`.

If you use `Template`, then nothing will automatically take original control, you should define complete template.

I'd recommend to create a normal `UserControl` if you want to simply combine several controls into one, way simpler than to deal with complete templates.

Comment: +1, use templates to *change the appearance* of a control, not to simply compose multiple elements together.

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought, but if I wrap the TextBox inside my costum control, I have to register all of the textbox properties just to bind them to the actual textbox inside my control. That's a bit ugly, too...
I know that AdornedElementPlaceHolder is ment to be used in conjunction with Validation.ErrorTemplate but I thought that there could be a similar approach for this kind of use-cases.